# validate iphone push notification token?

Tags: iphone, notifications, push, token

I've not yet implemented push notifications in my app.  My understanding is that the app running on the device must request a token, then send this token to my server, and that my server must pass this token to Apple whenever I want to push a message to the device / app.

**Is a requested push token specific to the app, or do all apps on the device share a token?**

**Is there any way for me to validate that the token the device sends to my server was indeed generated by a request within my app?**

I'm concerned about a possible spoof where a rogue app could send a valid token to my server that wasn't a token my app requested.  This would trick my service into sending push notifications to that device/app.

I understand this is an unlikely scenario.  I'm trying to create a mechanism to verify that when my app sends information to my server I am indeed talking with an instance of my app, not some rogue client.  Push notifications seem like a possible way to achieve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Is a requested push token specific to the app, or do all apps on the device share a token?**
No the requested token is specific to your Application and each device.

**Is there any way for me to validate that the token the device sends to my server was indeed generated by a request within my app?** 
There is a service with apple in which you can query and find out if a token is "still valid", this is used for things such as when a user deletes your application and their token is invalidated, you can query the service and check if the token is still valid and if not delete it from your database...So you can also use this service to make sure any tokens given are valid...anyway if u try to push to an invalid token i suspect nothing will happen...

hope this helps

Comment: The token is actually unique to the combination of device and application. So the same app, on the same iTunes account, on a different device gets a different token. That's so the user can control which devices the notifications get sent to.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278834/php-technique-to-query-the-apns-feedback-server for the validation

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)dToken { 

    NSString *strToken = [NSString 
                     stringWithFormat:@"%@",dToken];

    NSLog(@"deviceToken is : %@",strToken);

    strToken = [strToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    strToken = [strToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    strToken = [strToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"deviceToken is : %@",strToken);
}
```

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with the question.