# Trouble with UNUserNotificationSettings

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I got a question about **UNUserNotificationSettings**. Is there any method that we can use to turn on/off notification(sound, alert, badge) in iOs 10+? In iOs 9 and below, I used *registerUserNotificationSettings* method to turn on sound, alert, badge in the app but can't do the same in iOs 10+. Any suggestion for my case?

Answer (score 2):

for iOS 10, you can use method `requestAuthorizationWithOptions` like this:

```
//iOS 10
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"request authorization succeeded!");
    }
}];
```

This is the definition of the parameter `options` :

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UNAuthorizationOptions) {
    UNAuthorizationOptionBadge   = (1 << 0),
    UNAuthorizationOptionSound   = (1 << 1),
    UNAuthorizationOptionAlert   = (1 << 2),
    UNAuthorizationOptionCarPlay = (1 << 3),
} __IOS_AVAILABLE(10.0) __TVOS_AVAILABLE(10.0) __WATCHOS_AVAILABLE(3.0);
```

Comment: thank for your tip, but that method can't solve my problem

Comment: @A.D Do you want to be turn on/off after authorization?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want to do. I intended to use this method:
[center getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
                    }];
but it just get settings status, cannot update settings

Comment: unfortunately, you can't turn on/off the Push Notifications for your app from the app code, but you can get the status to guide the user to open

Comment: reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493949/enable-disable-apple-push-notification-from-iphone-app