# APNS: Push notification status

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am writing an app that receives Push notifications via the [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).

Is there a way to know whether a push notification sent via APNS has successfully arrived to the device?

Comment: Can you explain in brief ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what information is missing? I have sent a push notification, and I want to know whether it has arrived.

Comment: I don't think so. Then it would mean to find out if the receiver device is turned on or off.

Comment: So you'r asking in the app level or device level ?

Comment: as @arslanasim answered, Apple will not tell you if the push notification was delivered successfully or not but if you still want to track it nonetheless, you could play dirty and capsule a self generated token in the push notification payload. When the push notification is opened, respond with the token (_optionally, buffer it and wait for internet connection incase no network connectivity at the time of opening the push notification_). For this, you'll need to maintain a database of generated tokens sent and received. **But... I am not sure if Apple would be fine with this**

Comment: This question is a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493145/how-to-find-the-apple-push-notification-delivered-to-user-or-not-from-our-server

Comment: @EvaMadrazo Thanks, don't know how I missed it. Will vote to close the question.

Comment: @staticVoidMan Thanks - It's a nice hack but I don't want to cross any lines with Apple here.

Comment: @AdamMatan : +1 on that :P

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible to find whether it received by device or not,as php code will only connect to APNS server of apple. after that it is responsibility of apple server to send that message/notification to device.

Comment: Thanks, but this has nothing to do with PHP.